# Python RegEx to replace string

Tags: python, regex, string, list, replace

How do I use RegEx (or something else in Python) for the following requirement?
I need to:

1. Remove the word "dream" (including all its stems)
2. Remove All previous words (i.e. all words behind the word "dream")
3. Remove the Word next to it (in front of it/to the right of "dream")
4. Remove the word "to" from all phrases.

Input:

```
text = ["Dream of a car",
        "Dream to live in a world",
        "Dream about 8am every morning",
        "stopped dreaming today",
        "still dreaming of a car",
        "One more dream to come late tomorrow",
        "Dream coming to hope tomorrow"]
```

Required Output:

```
["a car",
 "live in a world",
 "8am every morning",
 " ",
 "a car",
 "come late tomorrow",
 "hope tomorrow"]
```

I tried:

```
result = [re.sub('Dream', '', a) for a in text]

# MyOutput
[' of a car', ' to live in a world', ' about 8am every morning', 'stopped dreaming today', 'still dreaming of a car', 'One more dream to come late tomorrow', ' coming to hope tomorrow']
```

Comment: The solution you propose could only ever do half of your first requirement, and doesn't even *attempt* to address the rest.

Comment: yes I dont know how to go about the rest :(

Comment: Also the output you claim does not match your input.

Comment: yes that's another mystery even though I ran it on the whole input.

Comment: No I mean what you claim your attempt does is not what it actually does, hence not a [mcve].

Comment: ^ Updated my output, apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives your required output

```
result = [re.sub(r'\bto\b *', '', re.sub(r'^.*Dream[^ ]* *[^ ]* *', '', a, flags=re.I)) for a in text]
```

If you only want to remove the to at the front

```
result = [re.sub(r'^.*Dream[^ ]* *[^ ]* *(\bto\b)? *', '', a, flags=re.I) for a in text]
```

Comment: Whoops, I forgot about that. Do you require removing it only at the front of the new text or everywhere? What about "Dream of running to school"? Should it be "running school" or "running to school"?

Comment: haha, no you are actually right, you suggestion fits me better, thanks!

Comment: Oh, and the previous version of the second regexp was not working with "Dreaming of tomorrow". Now it is fixed.